# Java 8: stop andThen chain

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I work in Java Project.
I have chain of andThen Operator, somthing like:

```
new xxx().andThen(new yyy()).andThen(new zzz()).apply();
```

xxx, yyy, zzz are all implement Function interface.

Sometimes, if specific conditional **in yyy.apply implementaion** is true, after execute yyy.apply, I want to stop the proccess and break without run **zzz.apply**.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

**For better understanding**, I give details about my case. I cannot show my code  - it is very long busyness logic and also secured, but I can describe my case:
My code goal is retrieve data-list from not-relational DB.
The logic about the retrieving is very complex.
So, I split the logic according to separated steps, each step implemented by consumer. Each consumer return to the next consumer the client -request with improvements that he execute.
For example, one step add additional-filters to the source-client-request. Other request analize the columns (that user asked to show in the grid) and convert them to the relevant column in DB.
One of my consumer, is specific for edge-cases, when we need first retrieve data from MY-SQL server and only after that continue retrieve from not-relational DB.
This is the point when I sometime want to stop.
becouse sometime I found in this point, according to the data that return from SQL, that I don't know to show any data to user (Even that at DB there is data).
This is the point I want to stop that chain.

Comment: what about `.andThen(x -> !x?new zzz().apply(x):x).`?

Comment: how would you possibly know that the return type of `xxx.apply` would be the input for `zzz` function if `yyy` is optional? Maybe you can be specific about the problem to find a specific solution. Nothing in general looks to be that simple and the question would need clarification as well.

Comment: Pass zzz to yyy in constructor and call zzz's apply from yyy when "special" condition is met. You know, andThen is not andMaybeThen

Comment: I have edited the question as you ask me, because according to your comment I understand that you not understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it separatly. If you use some stream, do one function, then implement you specific conditional as a `Predicate` and do another:

```
stream
    .map(new yyy())
    .filter(specificConditional)  // predicate
    .map(new zzz())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```